# how to display shared variables if the derivative section is in the next page crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I created two groups in CR report M then N, I created 4 sections in the N group header.
And in the M group header, I am incrementing the variable x by 1 in a formula:

```
WhilePrintingrecords;
x: = x+ 1;
```

in this four sections of the group header (group N) I displays the formula  affix:

```
while printingrecords;
shared numbervar x;
```

if at the end of the first page there 's not enough to write 4 sections Na, Nb, Nc and Nd, only the Na section is drawn in the first page, the Affix formula returns the value X, other sections Nb, Nc and Nd are shown in the following page but the formula affix returns nothing.

to solve the problem is I can check the "keep the unity of the group" option but I do not want regroup lines group in addition I want understand the cause of problem.

do you have ideas on this weird problem ?

Comment: Unless you are passing values between a main and a subreport, you should be using `global` scope, not `shared`.

Comment: i think Unless i am passing values between a main and a subreport, i should be using shared scope, not global.

Answer (score 1):

From Crystal Reports' documentation:

> The variable scopes available are:
>
> - Global
>
> The variable is available to formulas throughout the entire current report.
>
> - Shared
>
> The variable can be shared with a subreport as well as the entire current report.
>
> - Local
>
> The variable is specific and can only be used in the formula in which it is defined.

Your increment function needs to be `whileprintingrecords`:

```
// {@increment}

// 2nd pass
WhilePrintingRecords;

// scoped 'global'; increment
Numbervar x: = x+ 1;
```

Change display formula to use `global` scope:

```
// {@display}

// 2nd pass
WhilePrintingRecords;

// declare and display
Numbervar x;
```

This design:

[image]

Produces this preview:

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: my increment function is already 'whileprintingrecords' (third pass) i suppress shared ('global' scope only ), but i still have the same problem

Comment: thank you very much for your response, but i forget a formula in my problem in the page footer of the report i put this formula @GlobAdd